# How to enable GZip compression in Zend Server CE

Tags: flash-builder, zend-server

I work with Falsh buider and httpserver.
To accelerate result display, I'd like to activate compression on Zend Server.

I create .htaccess on /usr/local/zend/apache2/htdocs/, like this:

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c> 
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE 
# Insert filter on selected content types only 
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml 
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml 
# Don't compress images 
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$ no-gzip dont-vary 
# Make sure proxies don't deliver the wrong content 
Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary
```

I restart zend server, but compression seems to be desable.
Indeed on log, file size is the with compression and without.

So can you help me to solve that.

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure mod_deflate is installed?

Comment: Can you explain how to test that? Thanks

Comment: Simplest way might be to temporarily remove the `<IfModule...>` and `</IfModule>`. The page will error then when it tries to run the output filter commands. Alternatively create a phpinfo() page which will list the Apache modules installed.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to add

```
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-amf
```

since you may be indicating that you are using Flash remoting

Answer (score 0):

According your comment, I modify httpd.conf like that:

```
    LoadModule deflate_module modules/mod_deflate.so

<Location />
  <IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml application/xml application/x-amf
  </IfModule>
</Location>
```

Now delate_module is loaded.

But when I launch httpservice from flex with e4X resultformat, result file has same size that without compression, Why?

Thanks for helping